# Google Maps v3 with MarkerClustererer not working with createmarker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm trying to cluster my markers because the site is slow, but MarkerClusterer is not working on my site: http://www.estoestalca.cl

The code for the map is this:

```
    function initialize() {

  var styles = [ /* styles */ ];

  var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
    {name: "Styled Map"});

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-35.4292213, -71.6561387),
    streetViewControl: false,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
      mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
    mapOptions);

  var infowindow;
  var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map);

  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');

   downloadUrl("http://estoestalca.cl/?page_id=22", function(data) {
      var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), markers[i].getAttribute("permalink"), latlng, markers[i].getAttribute("imagen"), markers[i].getAttribute("category"), markers[i].getAttribute("tag"), markers[i].getAttribute("fecha1"), markers[i].getAttribute("fecha2"));
        markers.push(marker);
       }
       var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
     });

  function createMarker(name, permalink, latlng, imagen, category, tag, fecha1, fecha2) {
    var image = 'puntos/palta-trans.png';
    var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
        position: latlng,
        icon: image,
        title: category,
        label: category,
        labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
        labelClass: "label " + tag + " " + category, // the CSS class for the label
        labelInBackground: false
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
      var titulo = '<h2>' + name + '</h2>';
      var image = '<a class="open fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="' + permalink + '"><img src="' + imagen + '" alt="place" /></a>';
      var fecha = '<p class="fecha"><span class="date1">' + fecha1 + '</span> / <span class="date2">' + fecha2 + '</span></p>';
      var contentString = '<div class="info">' + image + fecha +'</div>';
      var myOptions = {
             content: contentString
            ,disableAutoPan: false
            ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, 0)
            ,zIndex: null
            ,boxStyle: { 
              background: "#000"
              ,opacity: 0.75
              ,width: "180px"
             }
            ,closeBoxMargin: "0px -3px 0px 0px"
            ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.jorgerock.com/CRUZ.png"
            ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(130, 230)
            ,isHidden: false
            ,pane: "floatPane"
            ,enableEventPropagation: false
            ,maxWidth: 77
            ,maxHeight:75
        };
      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(myOptions);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);

    });
    return marker;
  }


}
```

The main problem is that in the console say this about markerclusterer.js: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.

I can't find the problem, by the way, after trying to add this to my website all markers are working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`markers` is an array of XML DOM elements.

```
var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
```

`gmarkers` is the array of google.maps.Marker objects.

Create a gmarkers array and change this:

```
downloadUrl("http://estoestalca.cl/?page_id=22", function(data) {
  var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), markers[i].getAttribute("permalink"), latlng, markers[i].getAttribute("imagen"), markers[i].getAttribute("category"), markers[i].getAttribute("tag"), markers[i].getAttribute("fecha1"), markers[i].getAttribute("fecha2"));
    markers.push(marker);
   }
   var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
 });
```

To:

```
downloadUrl("http://estoestalca.cl/?page_id=22", function(data) {
  var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
    var marker = createMarker(markers[i].getAttribute("name"), markers[i].getAttribute("permalink"), latlng, markers[i].getAttribute("imagen"), markers[i].getAttribute("category"), markers[i].getAttribute("tag"), markers[i].getAttribute("fecha1"), markers[i].getAttribute("fecha2"));
    gmarkers.push(marker);
   }
   var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
 });
```

[working fiddle (with normal marker, MarkerWithLabel doesn't work)](http://jsfiddle.net/sagw2ato/)

Comment: How I create the array for gmarkers? Using the same value of markers? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but now the console give me this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function markerwithlabel.js:577`
That line is `this.label.setMap(theMap);`

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in MarkerWithLabel, if I use a [regular marker it works](http://jsfiddle.net/sagw2ato/)